# Why my if...else statement doesnt work where is my mistake and how to fix it?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

Here how i call my query and i want to use simple if...else statement but i make a mistake somewhere can someone explain me where and why ?

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con,$sql));
    echo mysqli_error($con);
    $number=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $brand = $row['brand'];
        $model = $row['model'];
        $reg_num = $row['reg_num'];
        $horse_powers = $row['horse_powers'];
        $color = $row['color'];
        echo $number;
        if($number<1){
            echo "No rented cars for this period !";
        }
        else{
        echo $brand;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is the output of: `echo $number;` and what do you expect to work? (Also it doesn't make sense to check in the while loop if you have under 1 row!)

Comment: What does `var_dump($number);` return?

Comment: Where's the mistake? What do you expect to happen? What happens? Is your query return the data you expect? Are the values of the variables what you expect?

Comment: `mysqli_error` only expects 1 parameter. Turn on error reporting.

Comment: I want `$row['horse_powers']` to be "turns into a unicorn"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
    $number = 0;
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if (!$result) 
         exit(mysqli_error($con));
    else
         $number = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($number==0) {
        echo "No rented cars for this period !";
    } else {
        while ($number){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
            $brand = $row['brand'];
            $model = $row['model'];
            $reg_num = $row['reg_num'];
            $horse_powers = $row['horse_powers'];
            $color = $row['color'];
            echo $brand;
            $number--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about fetching the result? `$row` is undefined!

Comment: `mysqli_error($con,$sql)` is incorrect - `mysqli_error()` only takes 1 parameter; the connection. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php `string mysqli_error ( mysqli $link )` - and `echo mysqli_error` that stands to fail http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php `printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I fixed that too (thanks for noticing me). Now is optimized and written in his style.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I mean he had basic mistakes in his code , so he don't seem's to have lots of programming experience! And the first 2 edit's couldn't work, and still he got upvotes and so on! *WTF*

Comment: @Rizier123 Accepted anwers can be questionable at times. I would take it up with the OP instead ;)

Answer (score 0):

The output of this if-statement will always be false.

```
if($number<1){
   echo "No rented cars for this period !";
}
else{
   echo $brand;
}
```

The while loop will not run if `$number < 1`. So if `$number < 1` it will never get to the if statement.